# R Timeline Without Dates

Tags: r, vistime

I'm trying to make a timeline like you'd make with any of the timevis, vistime, or timeline R packages, but I'm only interested in times and not dates. I don't mind putting a placeholder date in there, but it seems that all of these packages require the start and end times to include dates and include the date in the timeline.

I've been searching for ways to either not include dates in a timeline or only print the time but not the date in any of these package, but haven't been able to find anything. Does anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All of those packages use `as.POSIXct` under the hood, which requires objects to be `Date` objects and doesn't work with times only. So, if your data is about only one day, you can add the date on the clock times (using `paste`) and e.g. `vistime` will display only the time (ok, a date almost completely hidden in the corner):

```
dat <- data.frame(event = 1:2,
                    start = c("14:00", "16:00"),
                    end = c("15:30", "17:00"))

# add a Date
dat[,c("start", "end")] <- sapply(dat[,c("start", "end")], function(x) paste(Sys.Date(), x))

vistime(dat)
```

[image]

I use `vistime` version `0.7.0.9000` which can be obtained by executing `devtools::install_github("shosaco/vistime")`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to represent times without any date information, you should try out the package [hms](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/hms/index.html). It is part of the tidyverse collection and is described as:

> A simple class for storing durations or time-of-day values and displaying them in the hh:mm:ss format.

Example use:

```
library(hms)
hms(56, 34, 12)
#> 12:34:56
```

Comment: This definitely looks interesting, but it seems that the timeline packages don't accept hms objects as valid for the starts and ends.